# Magento - Shopping cart delete item is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento

I have update my store at last version 1.9.2.4 and I have ssl enable, after this my delete button from the shopping cart has stop working. I see in firebug this error:

```
ReferenceError: coShippingMethodForm is not defined
coShippingMethodForm.submit = function () { at line 655
```

At that line I have this function:

```
function getQuote() {
    $jq('#shipping-zip-form').attr('id','shipping-zip-form-ajax');
    var coShippingMethodFormAjax = new VarienForm('shipping-zip-form-ajax');

    **THIS IS THE LINE 655**  coShippingMethodForm.submit = function () {

        var country = $F('country');
        var optionalZip = false;

        for (i=0; i < countriesWithOptionalZip.length; i++) {
            if (countriesWithOptionalZip[i] == country) {
                optionalZip = true;
            }
        }
        if (optionalZip) {
            $('postcode').removeClassName('required-entry');
        }
        else {
            $('postcode').addClassName('required-entry');
        }
        if (this.validator.validate()) {
            this.form.submit();
        }
        console.log(countriesWithOptionalZip.length);
    }.bind(coShippingMethodFormAjax);
}
```

How I can solve this?

Thank you

Comment: can you please provide file path and name?

Comment: Hi, file path is: https://example.com/checkout/cart/delete/id/20383/form_key/e4W4gZZybGSWxqC1/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9udXRyaWphLmNvbS9jaGVja291dC9jYXJ0/form_key/e4W4gZZybGSWxqC1 and the name? what name do you need?

Comment: I need file name and its path where you get this error

Comment: here is the phtml where the button is: app/design/frontend/default/ma_sagitta/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

and where the js is: https://example.com/js/magentothem/ajax_cart_super.js

Comment: which plugin are you using for ajax cart ?

Comment: Magentothem_Ajaxcartsuper

Comment: ohh you have created variable like this

var coShippingMethodFormAjax

and you are using it like this

coShippingMethodForm

Comment: can you show me how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121416/discussion-between-robertd-and-sarfaraz-bheda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is your code shown above:

```
var coShippingMethodFormAjax = new VarienForm('shipping-zip-form-ajax');
```

Update line 655

FROM

```
coShippingMethodForm.submit = function () {
```

TO

```
coShippingMethodFormAjax .submit = function () {
```

Comment: the error is not there now, but the ajax remain loading and nothing happend

Comment: we can talk in chat?